# Formatting Filled Polygons within R-Plots

Tags: plot, graph, colors, polygon

I am trying to make my red distribution look like the white and blue distributions. I do not want a bolded red line surrounding the plot. Here is my image:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzdPh.jpg)

Here is the code:

```
plot(x = seq(-30, 30, .01), y = dnorm(seq(-30, 30, .01), mean = 12.2000, sd = 5.8445),col = rgb(1, 0, 0, alpha = 0.80))
lines(x = seq(-30, 30, .01), y = dnorm(seq(-30, 30, .01), mean = .4333, sd = 5.8445),col = rgb(1, 1, 1, alpha = 0.80))
lines(x = seq(-30, 30, .01), y = dnorm(seq(-30, 30, .01), mean = -13.333, sd = 5.8445),col = rgb(0, 0.20, 1, alpha = 0.80))

polygon(x = seq(-30, 30, .01), y = dnorm(seq(-30, 30, .01), mean = 12.2000, sd = 5.8445), col = rgb(1, 0, 0, alpha = 0.80))
polygon(x = seq(-30, 30, .01), y = dnorm(seq(-30, 30, .01), mean = .4333, sd = 5.8445), col = rgb(1, 1, 1, alpha = 0.80))
polygon(x = seq(-30, 30, .01), y = dnorm(seq(-30, 30, .01), mean = -13.333, sd = 5.8445), col = rgb(0, 0.20, 1, alpha = 0.80))

legend(x= "topright", legend=c("Mississippi", "Florida", "New Jersey"), 
   fill = c(rgb(1, 0, 0, alpha = 0.80),
            rgb(1, 1, 1, alpha = 0.80),
            rgb(0, 0.20, 1, alpha = 0.80)))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.